# React Typescript SetStateAction Generic mixup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I personally didn't know how to word this question. The issue I am running into involves me passing down a `setState` hook into a child component, but it's not always the same `setState` action if that makes sense.

For example, lets say i have `setState(a)` which is expecting a parameter of `string` and that same child component may end up getting a `setState(b)` which is expecting a parameter of `number`... now in reality, the parameters that the child is expecting are different types of generics if that makes sense.

So for simplicity, I would create the component which expects one prop that would involve either the `setState(a)` or the `setState(b)`. Now I get an error saying type `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | number | undefined>>` is not assignable to type `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | undefined>>`

How do I set it so it can expect either a `string`, `number`, or `undefined`. Understanding that in some situations a number is not even an option for it or a string is not even an option for it to accept as a parameter.

SORRY FOR THE CONFUSING QUESTION, I tried my best to explain this. I'm somewhat new to Typescript and am trying to figure out the best way to work with it and React at the same time! (I'm somewhat new to hooks as well too!)

Thank you all in advance!!

Edit: A better example

```
  const [a, setA] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [b, setB] = useState<number | undefined>();

  if (something) {
    return (
      <CustomChildComponent useThisState={setA}/>
    )
  } else if (somethingElse) {
    return (
      <CustomChildComponent useThisState={setB}/>
    )
  }
```

The Error in `CustomChildComponent` when passing in this prop will say:

`(JSX attribute) useThisState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | number | undefined>>`
`Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | undefined>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | number | undefined>>'.`

I hope this clarifies the issue a bit more!

Comment: How is your initial state value defined?

Comment: @simmer

`const [a, setA] = setState<string | undefined>();`

`const [b, setB] = setState<number | undefined>();`

I hope this helps clear anything up!

Comment: Getting there! Could you edit your question to show some example code? Also, I'm assuming you mean `useState`, not `setState` in your comment?

Comment: @simmer I'll edit it now. Also, I mean `setA` and `setB` in this example. I'm using React Hooks, incase we're talking about the same thing!

Comment: @thatdevopNB This helped me! https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-typeing-custom-hooks/